# Send NSDistributedNotification and get a response

Tags: cocoa, firebreath

I created a firebreath plugin that sends a notification to a cocoa application. Is there any way to get a response from the application if the notification was recived successfully?

Comment: If you only need to know if it was received, you could have your Cocoa app NSLog something...

Comment: But I need to send the response back to the plugin, like a confirmation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can receive them in *firebreath* plugins, why don't you send an `NSDistributedNotification` back? I've used this mechanism to communicate an app with a background agent and it works perfectly.

```
[[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
    postNotificationName:<#ping-or-pong#> 
    object:<#sender-id#> 
    userInfo:nil 
    deliverImmediately:NO];
```

You can use `<#sender-id#>` (a string, for instance) to allow each part to skip its own notifications.

Comment: I don't know how NSDistributedNotification works; in a NPAPI plugin (on Mac, all FireBreath plugins are NPAPI) you don't have a NSWindow or an NSApplication, but there is a NSThread running (things like performSelectorOnMainThread work), so you may be able to use it if it doesn't require them other things

Comment: I am having problems to add the notification observer in my firebreath plugin, beacuse it requires that I define a selector method and set the observer. If I define the selector in objective-c it is throwing me a syntax error. Also, I am not able to add "self" as observer. I have another objective-c code in my plugin and is working ok. Here is my post related to this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680145/need-to-add-a-nsdistributednotification-observer-in-my-firebreath-project